# Data Visualization Blog using a Static Site Generator

Tags: data-visualization, docpad, static-site, hexo

I recently came across static site generators like Hexo and DocPad. The ease with which the blog can be built is incredible. Are there plugins that integrate with these generators to include interactive charts on your blog? Are static site generators are a good choice to build such type of a blog? The blog that I am looking to build is something like this one: http://www.informationisbeautiful.net/

Comment: I see no particular problem with using DocPad for such a site. There are no plugins for the specific task and you would probably need some other library to generate the charts themselves and then include them as page elements. The informationisbeautiful site includes the charts as images, so they are just straight foward img tags like any other.

Answer (score 0):

If you refers to static images there is no need for plugins, just put images in place and generate your site.

For dynamic charts I think you will be using javascript in a library of some sort, just put the scripts you need in the right folder for docpad/hexo. Probably you will need to edit your pages as HTML and not markdown to make use of this library or you can modify your theme for that. In any case I think it is a bit application specific but very feasible.

good luck